# ArrayList of type 2D array in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, multidimensional-array

I have declared an ArrayList along the lines of this at the beginning of my code:

```
ArrayList<int[][]> arraylists = new ArrayList<>();
```

Since Netbeans is not giving me an error, I am assuming that syntax wise, this is a valid declaration.

I added a 2D array element like this:

```
int[][] newarray = {{0},{0}};
arraylists.add(newarray);
```

I called upon the ArrayList like so:

```
int[][] array = arraylists.get(0);
```

Since I have already added something to the ArrayList, I will not get an index out of bounds exception.

However, it is not getting the 2D Array at index 0. To debug I tried doing this:

```
System.out.println("testing");
int[][] array = arraylists.get(0);
```

The output is this:`testing`

However, when I tried doing this:

```
int[][] array = arraylists.get(0);
System.out.println("testing");
```

The output is nothing

I think this means that there is a problem with getting the 2D array within the ArrayList as no other error pops up. I think it would be good to mention that nothing else after getting the 2D array from the ArrayList works. So the program stop there. I am just beginning my code so this is just about all I have so far, and I plan on continuing the code once this problem is resolved. Note that Netbeans is not alerting me saying that there is anything wrong. It just isn't working...

Can anyone help me to identify what is wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will fix your problem, but try adding 'int[][]' between the <> on the right side of the =.

Comment: Is the code very short? You aren't giving us much to go on and I do not see a problem looking at what you currently have posted so you might want to post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I set up a test scenario and it worked fine for me. We need to see more of the code. (i.e. code you use to add `int[][]` array to the arraylist)

Comment: @GeorgeMulligan Yes it is in its beginning stages, I wanted to test this idea to see if it would work before adding more. But it does not so, this is pretty much what I have. I have editted code, I have added the code used to add the element to the arraylist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably just Netbeans being silly. Try cleaning the project and rebuild. This code works just fine:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<int[][]> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new int[][]{{1,2}, {3,4}});
    int[][] twoD = list.get(0);
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoD));
}
```

Comment: I don't know, why, it still does not work for me. Could it possibly be because I have the ArrayList set as a global variable?

Comment: For me, the: System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(twoD));  Doesn't print anything

Comment: Can you report the error you get when you run it?

I say this, because the code written by @Ulises should run perfectly.

Comment: @AntonioK did you copy paste this code and it didn't print anything?

Comment: @Bifz I did, and it worked. However, I added my 2D array and it did not. which is what I don't get. It may be because I have the List set as a global variable, as I need it in multiple methods. But the fact that it is Global shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: @DebosmitRay This code works. but when I apply it to my program, it doesn't. The only difference is that my 2D array is a big, 9 by 9 array and that the List is declared globally.

Comment: @AntonioK No, it doesn't matter. As long as you set it's value before adding and don't change it's reference before retrieving your array.

Comment: @Bifz I applied it to my code, put a System.out.println statement before and after the code. The one that was put before was printed, but the one that was put after, was not. Which means that my code is in a sense, stopping or is getting stuck where I am getting the array

Comment: @Bifz I found the problem. I wasn't statically declaring the ArrayList... Thank you for your help